# Data driven pages to line up?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, data-driven-pages

When I create a map book, using data driven pages, when I place teh actual pages side by side there is some overlap, so the pages do not line up exactly. Is there a way to clip the overlap so that the pages are fairly seamless in the map book?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the overlap can be adjusted in the [DDP toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003n000000). In the second tab "Extent" there is the option to set the map extent. If you change this value to 100% there should be no overlap between your pages assuming the layer you are using lines up correctly.

[image]